# How to extract HTML code for a table in NASDAQ site using Beautiful Soup and Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

So basically, I want to read the HTML code for this table in the following link:
https://www.nasdaq.com/symbol/aapl/revenue-eps

To do this, I have used python and Beautiful Soup.

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
url = urllib.urlopen("https://www.nasdaq.com/symbol/aapl/revenue-eps")
mylist = []
soup = BeautifulSoup(url,"html.parser")
my_table = soup.find('table',{'class':'ipos'})
print(my_table)
```

The code above is what I have attempted. When I right click and select inspect on the table, the table name I find is called 'ipos' but when I try to put it in this code, it just doesnt seem to work. The only output I get is "None"

I have tested this with another site, and it works perfectly. When i used that link and used the name of the table in that HTML code, I am able to obtain the HTML code for that table perfectly. However, that is not the case with this one. Any assistance on this would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The table you see is inside the `<iframe>`. To load the content of this `<iframe>` you  can use this script:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.nasdaq.com/symbol/aapl/revenue-eps"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text,"html.parser")

iframe_url = soup.select_one('iframe#frmMain')['src']

requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings()
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(iframe_url, verify=False).text,"html.parser")

table = soup.select_one('table.ipos')

for tr in table.select('tr'):
    for td in tr.select('td'):
        print('{: <30}'.format(td.get_text(strip=True)), end='')
    print()
```

Prints:

```
Revenue / EPS Summary *                                     Revenue / EPS Summary *                                     
                              Revenue / EPS Summary *                                     


Fiscal Quarter                                              2019(Fiscal Year)                                           2018(Fiscal Year)                                           2017(Fiscal Year)             


December                                                                                                                
Revenue                       $84,310(m)                    $88,293(m)                    $78,351(m)                    
EPS                           4.18 (12/29/2018)             3.89 (12/30/2017)             3.36 (12/31/2016)             
Dividends                     0.73                          0.63                          0.57                          

March                                                                                                                   
Revenue                       $58,015(m)                    $61,137(m)                    $52,896(m)                    
EPS                           2.48 (3/30/2019)              2.74 (3/31/2018)              2.1 (4/1/2017)                
Dividends                     0.77                          0.73                          0.63                          

June                                                                                                                    
Revenue                       $53,809(m)                    $53,265(m)                    $45,408(m)                    
EPS                           2.2 (6/29/2019)               2.36 (6/30/2018)              1.68 (7/1/2017)               
Dividends                     0.77                          0.73                          0.63                          

September  (FYE)                                                                                                        
Revenue                                                     $62,900(m)                    $52,579(m)                    
EPS                                                         2.92 (9/29/2018)              2.07 (9/30/2017)              
Dividends                                                   0.73                          0.63                          


Totals                                                                                                                  
Revenue                       $196,134(m)                   $265,595(m)                   $229,234(m)                   
EPS                           8.86                          11.91                         9.21                          
Dividends                     2.27                          2.82                          2.46                          

Previous 3 Years
```

Answer (score 1):

The table loads inside an `iframe`. If you inspect the network requests made by this page then you will find a request like this:

```
https://fundamentals.nasdaq.com/redpage.asp?selected=AAPL&market=NASDAQ-GS&LogoPath=https%3a%2f%2fwww.nasdaq.com%2flogos%2fAAPL.GIF&coname=Apple%20Inc.
```

This is the url that loads the table into this page. Using the above url you can find the table.

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
url = urllib.urlopen("https://fundamentals.nasdaq.com/redpage.asp?selected=AAPL&market=NASDAQ-GS&LogoPath=https%3a%2f%2fwww.nasdaq.com%2flogos%2fAAPL.GIF&coname=Apple%20Inc.")
mylist = []
soup = BeautifulSoup(url,"html.parser")
my_table = soup.find('table',{'class':'ipos'})
print(my_table)
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate on how you managed to generate that link?